# Redux-form: input value is not yet set onChange of input

Tags: redux-form

When the user picks a value from a select dropdown, the `onChange` calls a function in the parent container. There I need to check which fields are filled.

But it appears that the value hasn't been set in the form yet. 
I have tried to use the **selectors** `valid` and `getFormvalues`, but they are not updated with the latest form value change.

See this  [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/x7yxp4lkm4).

If I print `getFormvalues` in the render of the form component, it is updated, but I can't handle the form there.

So how can I handle the form after the user picks a value, where the form is updated?

Answer (score 0):

You are already receiving values in the `SimpleFormContainer` due to `connect`. You don't need the callback from `SimpleFormContainer` to `SimpleForm`. You can use the `componentWillReceiveProps` in the `SimpleFormContainer` to check the values update and do whatever you want.

The final code might look like:-

```
class SimpleFormContainer extends React.Component {

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextValues) {
    if (this.props.formValues !== nextValues.formValues){
      console.log(nextValues.formValues)
    }
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <SimpleForm onSubmit={showResults}/>
    )
  }
}


SimpleFormContainer = connect(
  state => ({
    formValues: getFormValues('simple')(state)
  }),
  { getFormValues }
)(SimpleFormContainer);
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/64x02n0673)